# Change the mysql.sock that the system PHP uses

Tags: php, mysql, macports, php-cli

In the past I had installed MySQL as part of XAMPP in `/Applications/XAMPP/` and the PHP that the system used (e.g. from command line) used `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to connect with MySQL.

Now I have installed MySQL 5 with macports and I want my system PHP to be able to use that. I think I must set PHP to use `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock` but where do I set this? Is there a `php.ini` for CLI PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `php-cli.ini` in `/opt/local/etc/` (or where-ever PHP is installed). It should be in the same folder as your normal `php.ini` is in. If it's not, copy `php.ini-dist` or `php.ini` (which should also be in the same folder) to `php-cli.ini`.